# Testing OpenId login, but how to log out?

Tags: web-applications, openid, logout

I am developing a web page which allows login via openid. Thanks to restlet's openid implementation, it works fine.

But: When I logged in, I would like to test again, maybe with another provider or because I suspect a bug etc. The problem is: the page remembers that I was logged in. I immediately get my protected page instead of the redirect to my OpenIdProvider.

Even deleting all cookies, restarting the browser and restarting the development sever makes no difference. How can I log out and get a second try?

My OpenIdProviders are google and myopenid (two accounts, because I want to make sure both providers work with my page). Visiting accounts.google.com/Logout does not help either.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, restarting the browser does result in my OpenID test user being logged out from the OpenID provider (Gmail in my case). (I mean restarting the browser from within the test suite, automatically.)

I use Selenium and Chrome, see: http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/ChromeDriver

When ChromeDriver starts Chrome, it specifies many command line options, which apparently starts a Chrome browser that remembers nothing from the past (no plugins, no cookies (I think), not logged in to anywhere, as far as I've noticed).

So, perhaps you're using another browser or testing framework that doesn't reset the browser's state between each test run. And one solution could be to use to Selenium + Chrome and ChromeDriver.